# Can minors withdraw check?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, check, minor, money-order

I want to send a gift - named check. The issuer is a US resident, sending from the US. The minor is a US non-resident, located in the US.

Can I go to the bank, issue the check with the kid's name on that check, so that kid will grab parents, go to the bank and get the cash?

Comment: as I mentioned this is about a non-resident minor. and eventually, I grew up in another country and don't know whether it is legal or not here. thank you for your patience and knowledge sharing.
I understand I can give some cash directly. but to withdraw the cash in a bank some documents may be requested (and non-resident minor has no docs), and if the check is not given to the parent (kid's name) the bank may decline to cash it

Comment: Your question is based on some misguided notions, that indicate more familiarity with prepaid cards than with checks and checking accounts. You withdraw money **from a bank**, not from a check; the check just says "how much" and "from whom".    This question really is like many here "How can I cash an American check in Country X?"  If the minor has a bank account, then the answer is no different from all those other questions; if the minor does not have a bank account, then they're in a bit of a pickle.

Comment: no docs, no account, only parents with docs. but the kid name should be on the check. kid should go to the bank (with parents) give the check and get a cash

Comment: Where?  London or a tiny village in Laos?

Comment: oh, I see that's the question. I was sure when I mentioned ssn and US it is clear that the question is about the US. I've updated the question. everything is about the US: issuer, receiver (kid), parents. everyone and everything is happening in the US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child should be able to *countersign* the check, and a parent<sup>*</sup> deposits it in the parent's account.

Because it takes a couple of business days for the check to "clear" (be acknowledged by the other bank, and money transferred), the parent would then have to withdraw that much money from their own account and give it to the child.

If someone gave my child (referred to as Alice) a check like this, I'd treat it as a learning experience, and go with Alice to the bank and have her countersign the check in front of the teller.

<sup>*</sup>  Actually, **anybody**; a countersigned check is almost as good as cash.  All that's stopping a thief from stealing a check, forging a signature and depositing it in their own account is a teller verifying the countersigned signature.

Answer (score 1):

A child's parent can deposit or cash a check received by the child. To endorse the check, the parent signs his/her own name, then prints the explanation (Father) or (Mother) next to the signature.

Comment: am I right the check's receiver can be the child name only? but in the bank child should go with a parent and there will no be an issue to cash it with the parent's signature only?

Comment: Correct. And there is no need to bring the child to the bank.

Comment: that is the main part: the money is not a gift itself, the process is a gift :)